# Display specific content with a custom select

Tags: javascript, html, css, select

I am using this code for my custom select: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_custom_select.asp

I'm also trying to display specific content when an option is selected. I've tried some "swap content" javascript but it doesn't work with this custom select.

***In fact it actually works but only with the "original" select element but at the time I put in on display:none to only work with my custom select it's not working anymore,***

If someone has a code to display specific content with this custom select options I would appreciate

Otherwise here is my test code if you need it :

```js
/*Button list*/

$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".custom-select").change(function(){
        $(this).find("option:selected").each(function(){
            var optionValue = $(this).attr("value");
            if(optionValue){
                $(".liste").not("." + optionValue).hide();
                $("." + optionValue).show();
            } else{
                $(".liste").hide();
            }
        });
    }).change();
});


/*Btn Content display*/
jQuery(function(){;       
          $('.swap-button').click(function(){   
          $('.targetDiv').hide();
          $('#div'+$(this).attr('target')).show();
          $('.swap-button').removeClass("active");
          $(this).addClass("active");
          });
                   
});


/*Custom select*/

var x, i, j, l, ll, selElmnt, a, b, c;
/*look for any elements with the class "custom-select":*/
x = document.getElementsByClassName("custom-select");
l = x.length;
for (i = 0; i < l; i++) {
  selElmnt = x[i].getElementsByTagName("select")[0];
  ll = selElmnt.length;

  /*for each element, create a new DIV that will act as the selected item:*/
  a = document.createElement("DIV");
  a.setAttribute("class", "select-selected");
  a.innerHTML = selElmnt.options[selElmnt.selectedIndex].innerHTML;
  x[i].appendChild(a);

  /*for each element, create a new DIV that will contain the option list:*/
  b = document.createElement("DIV");
  b.setAttribute("class", "select-items select-hide");
  for (j = 1; j < ll; j++) {

    /*for each option in the original select element,
    create a new DIV that will act as an option item:*/
    c = document.createElement("DIV");
    c.innerHTML = selElmnt.options[j].innerHTML;
    c.addEventListener("click", function(e) {

        /*when an item is clicked, update the original select box,
        and the selected item:*/
        var y, i, k, s, h, sl, yl;
        s = this.parentNode.parentNode.getElementsByTagName("select")[0];
        sl = s.length;
        h = this.parentNode.previousSibling;
        for (i = 0; i < sl; i++) {
          if (s.options[i].innerHTML == this.innerHTML) {
            s.selectedIndex = i;
            h.innerHTML = this.innerHTML;
            y = this.parentNode.getElementsByClassName("same-as-selected");
            yl = y.length;
            for (k = 0; k < yl; k++) {
              y[k].removeAttribute("class");
            }
            this.setAttribute("class", "same-as-selected");
            break;
          }
        }
        h.click();
    });
    b.appendChild(c);
  }
  x[i].appendChild(b);
  a.addEventListener("click", function(e) {

      /*when the select box is clicked, close any other select boxes,
      and open/close the current select box:*/
      e.stopPropagation();
      closeAllSelect(this);
      this.nextSibling.classList.toggle("select-hide");
      this.classList.toggle("select-arrow-active");
    });
}
function closeAllSelect(elmnt) {
  /*a function that will close all select boxes in the document,
  except the current select box:*/
  var x, y, i, xl, yl, arrNo = [];
  x = document.getElementsByClassName("select-items");
  y = document.getElementsByClassName("select-selected");
  xl = x.length;
  yl = y.length;
  for (i = 0; i < yl; i++) {
    if (elmnt == y[i]) {
      arrNo.push(i)
    } else {
      y[i].classList.remove("select-arrow-active");
    }
  }
  for (i = 0; i < xl; i++) {
    if (arrNo.indexOf(i)) {
      x[i].classList.add("select-hide");
    }
  }
}
/*if the user clicks anywhere outside the select box,
then close all select boxes:*/
document.addEventListener("click", closeAllSelect);
```

```css
/*Buttons list*/
.liste {
  display:none;
  margin: 15px 15px;
   }

.targetDiv {
  display:none;
  margin: 15px 15px;
   }
 
   .swap-button{
   display:inline-block;
   background:#ffff;
   cursor:pointer;
   color: #00205b;
}

.active{
   background:#00205B; 
   color: #eee;
  display:inline;
  }

/* Custom select: */

/* The container must be positioned relative: */
.custom-select {
  position: relative;
  font-family: Arial;
}

.custom-select select {
  display: ; /*hide original SELECT element: */
}

.select-selected {
  background-color: DodgerBlue;
  width: 50px;
  margin: 10px;
}

/* Style the arrow inside the select element: */
.select-selected:after {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  top: 14px;
  right: 10px;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border: 6px solid transparent;
  border-color: #fff transparent transparent transparent;
}

/* Point the arrow upwards when the select box is open (active): */
.select-selected.select-arrow-active:after {
  border-color: transparent transparent #fff transparent;
  top: 7px;
}

/* style the items (options), including the selected item: */
.select-items div,.select-selected {
  color: #ffffff;
 padding: 8px 5px;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  border-color: transparent transparent rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) transparent;
  cursor: pointer;
    width: 150px;

}

/* Style items (options): */
.select-items {
  position: absolute;
  padding: 8px 5px;
  background-color: DodgerBlue;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 99;
    width: 150px;
  margin: 10px ;
}

/* Hide the items when the select box is closed: */
.select-hide {
  display: none;
}

.select-items div:hover, .same-as-selected {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);

}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="custom-select">

  <select>
    <option value="">Select</option>
    <option value="orange">Orange</option>
    <option value="lemon">Lemon</option>
    <option value="apple">Apple</option>
  </select>
</div>

<div>

  <div class="liste orange">
    <button class="swap-button" target="1">orange btn1</button>
    <button class="swap-button" target="2">orange btn2</button>
    <button class="swap-button" target="3">orange btn3</button>
  </div>

  <div class="liste lemon">
    <button class="swap-button" target="4">lemon btn1</button>
    <button class="swap-button" target="5">lemon btn2</button>
    <button class="swap-button" target="6">lemon btn3</button>
  </div>

  <div class="liste apple">
    <button class="swap-button" target="7">apple btn1</button>
    <button class="swap-button" target="8">apple btn2</button>
    <button class="swap-button" target="9">apple btn3</button>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="contentarea">
  <section>
    <div id="div1" class="targetDiv">orange btn1 content</div>
    <div id="div2" class="targetDiv">orange btn2 content</div>
    <div id="div3" class="targetDiv">orange btn3 content</div>
  </section>

  <section>
    <div id="div4" class="targetDiv">lemon btn1 content</div>
    <div id="div5" class="targetDiv">lemon btn2 content</div>
    <div id="div6" class="targetDiv">lemon btn3 content</div>
  </section>

  <section>
    <div id="div7" class="targetDiv">apple btn1 content</div>
    <div id="div8" class="targetDiv">apple btn2 content</div>
    <div id="div9" class="targetDiv">apple btn3 content</div>
  </section>
</div>
```

Thanks

Comment: I wonder why this blue button not showing in my browser ? Also please make your question more clear because`swap-button` are working fine

Comment: swap-button are working fine when they are displayed but the thing is they should be different for each option selected : If I select lemon I should have lemon btn1, lemon btn2 and lemon btn3. Wich is working only with the original select

Comment: I can't see that blue select at all after copying code. I don't know what is the problem. Are you using any CSS/JS library other than jQuery?

Comment: Hum no not all, I've tried on safari and chrome and I can see it, are you on one of these ?

Comment: I am using Chrome based UC Browser. Tried on Mozilla too. Should I place this script in `<body>`? I am pasting it in `<head>` for now

Comment: I'm placing it in head aswell

Comment: OK it worked when I placed it after everything inside `<body>`. Now I can see that blue button

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out this snippet:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Test</title>
    <!-- JQuery -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <style type="text/css">
        /*Buttons list*/
        .liste {
            display:none;
            margin: 15px 15px;
        }

        .targetDiv {
            display:none;
            margin: 15px 15px;
        }

        .swap-button{
            display:inline-block;
            background:#ffff;
            cursor:pointer;
            color: #00205b;
        }

        .active{
            background:#00205B; 
            color: #eee;
            display:inline;
        }

        /* Custom select: */

        /* The container must be positioned relative: */
        .custom-select {
            position: relative;
            font-family: Arial;
        }

        .custom-select select {
            display: ; /*hide original SELECT element: */
        }

        .select-selected {
            background-color: DodgerBlue;
            width: 50px;
            margin: 10px;
        }

        /* Style the arrow inside the select element: */
        .select-selected:after {
            position: absolute;
            content: "";
            top: 14px;
            right: 10px;
            width: 0;
            height: 0;
            border: 6px solid transparent;
            border-color: #fff transparent transparent transparent;
        }

        /* Point the arrow upwards when the select box is open (active): */
        .select-selected.select-arrow-active:after {
            border-color: transparent transparent #fff transparent;
            top: 7px;
        }

        /* style the items (options), including the selected item: */
        .select-items div,.select-selected {
            color: #ffffff;
            padding: 8px 5px;
            border: 1px solid transparent;
            border-color: transparent transparent rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) transparent;
            cursor: pointer;
            width: 150px;

        }

        /* Style items (options): */
        .select-items {
            position: absolute;
            padding: 8px 5px;
            background-color: DodgerBlue;
            top: 100%;
            left: 0;
            right: 0;
            z-index: 99;
            width: 150px;
            margin: 10px ;
        }

        /* Hide the items when the select box is closed: */
        .select-hide {
            display: none;
        }

        .select-items div:hover, .same-as-selected {
            background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);

        }
    </style>

</head>
<body>
    <div class="custom-select">

        <select>
            <option value="">Select</option>
            <option value="orange">Orange</option>
            <option value="lemon">Lemon</option>
            <option value="apple">Apple</option>
        </select>
    </div>

    <div>

        <div class="liste orange">
            <button class="swap-button" target="1">orange btn1</button>
            <button class="swap-button" target="2">orange btn2</button>
            <button class="swap-button" target="3">orange btn3</button>
        </div>

        <div class="liste lemon">
            <button class="swap-button" target="4">lemon btn1</button>
            <button class="swap-button" target="5">lemon btn2</button>
            <button class="swap-button" target="6">lemon btn3</button>
        </div>

        <div class="liste apple">
            <button class="swap-button" target="7">apple btn1</button>
            <button class="swap-button" target="8">apple btn2</button>
            <button class="swap-button" target="9">apple btn3</button>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="contentarea">
        <section>
            <div id="div1" class="targetDiv">orange btn1 content</div>
            <div id="div2" class="targetDiv">orange btn2 content</div>
            <div id="div3" class="targetDiv">orange btn3 content</div>
        </section>

        <section>
            <div id="div4" class="targetDiv">lemon btn1 content</div>
            <div id="div5" class="targetDiv">lemon btn2 content</div>
            <div id="div6" class="targetDiv">lemon btn3 content</div>
        </section>

        <section>
            <div id="div7" class="targetDiv">apple btn1 content</div>
            <div id="div8" class="targetDiv">apple btn2 content</div>
            <div id="div9" class="targetDiv">apple btn3 content</div>
        </section>
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        function func(select){
            $(select).find("option:selected").each(function(){
                var optionValue = $(this).attr("value");
                if(optionValue){
                    $(".liste").not("." + optionValue).hide();
                    $("." + optionValue).show();
                } else{
                    $(".liste").hide();
                }
            });
        }

        /*Button list*/
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $(".custom-select").change(function(){
                func(this);
            }).change();
        });



        /*Btn Content display*/
        jQuery(function(){;       
            $('.swap-button').click(function(){   
                $('.targetDiv').hide();
                $('#div'+$(this).attr('target')).show();
                $('.swap-button').removeClass("active");
                $(this).addClass("active");
            });
            
        });


        /*Custom select*/

        var x, i, j, l, ll, selElmnt, a, b, c;
        /*look for any elements with the class "custom-select":*/
        x = document.getElementsByClassName("custom-select");
        l = x.length;
        for (i = 0; i < l; i++) {
            selElmnt = x[i].getElementsByTagName("select")[0];
            ll = selElmnt.length;

            /*for each element, create a new DIV that will act as the selected item:*/
            a = document.createElement("DIV");
            a.setAttribute("class", "select-selected");
            a.innerHTML = selElmnt.options[selElmnt.selectedIndex].innerHTML;
            x[i].appendChild(a);

            /*for each element, create a new DIV that will contain the option list:*/
            b = document.createElement("DIV");
            b.setAttribute("class", "select-items select-hide");
            for (j = 1; j < ll; j++) {

    /*for each option in the original select element,
    create a new DIV that will act as an option item:*/
    c = document.createElement("DIV");
    c.innerHTML = selElmnt.options[j].innerHTML;
    c.addEventListener("click", function(e) {

        /*when an item is clicked, update the original select box,
        and the selected item:*/
        var y, i, k, s, h, sl, yl;
        s = this.parentNode.parentNode.getElementsByTagName("select")[0];
        sl = s.length;
        h = this.parentNode.previousSibling;
        for (i = 0; i < sl; i++) {
            if (s.options[i].innerHTML == this.innerHTML) {
                s.selectedIndex = i;
                h.innerHTML = this.innerHTML;
                y = this.parentNode.getElementsByClassName("same-as-selected");
                yl = y.length;
                for (k = 0; k < yl; k++) {
                    y[k].removeAttribute("class");
                }
                this.setAttribute("class", "same-as-selected");
                break;
            }
        }
        func(s);
        h.click();
    });
    b.appendChild(c);
}
x[i].appendChild(b);
a.addEventListener("click", function(e) {

      /*when the select box is clicked, close any other select boxes,
      and open/close the current select box:*/
      e.stopPropagation();
      closeAllSelect(this);
      this.nextSibling.classList.toggle("select-hide");
      this.classList.toggle("select-arrow-active");
  });
}
function closeAllSelect(elmnt) {
  /*a function that will close all select boxes in the document,
  except the current select box:*/
  var x, y, i, xl, yl, arrNo = [];
  x = document.getElementsByClassName("select-items");
  y = document.getElementsByClassName("select-selected");
  xl = x.length;
  yl = y.length;
  for (i = 0; i < yl; i++) {
    if (elmnt == y[i]) {
        arrNo.push(i)
    } else {
        y[i].classList.remove("select-arrow-active");
    }
  }
  for (i = 0; i < xl; i++) {
    if (arrNo.indexOf(i)) {
        x[i].classList.add("select-hide");
    }
  }
}
/*if the user clicks anywhere outside the select box,
then close all select boxes:*/
document.addEventListener("click", closeAllSelect);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Funcnality of `$(".custom-select").change()` is moved to function `func(select)`, where select is reference to HTML `<select>` tag. This avoids code repition.

Inside `c.addEventListener("click", function(e)` we called newly created function `func(s)` with s as argument, as s refers to the select element.